# How to use sum and order by in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to return a sum row from my table and order with the sum result.

My sql like this:

```
self.db_user_online.query(
    MeleeGameData,
    func.sum(MeleeGameData.core_data).label("ct")
).\
    group_by(MeleeGameData.ccid).\
    filter_by(mid=self.cycle_id).\
    order_by("ct desc").\
    all()
```

Debug echo sql:

```
SELECT fiels..., sum(t_act_melee_game_data.core_data) AS ct
FROM t_act_melee_game_data
WHERE t_act_melee_game_data.mid = %s
GROUP BY t_act_melee_game_data.ccid
ORDER BY ct DESC
```

But it's can't work..

Comment: Do you know how to write the raw SQL that you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with your SQL code; I suppose you want to group by every `ccid` and then sum the corresponding data (I took out the filter for simplicity):

```
SELECT t_act_melee_game_data.ccid,
       sum(t_act_melee_game_data.core_data) AS ct
FROM t_act_melee_game_data
GROUP BY t_act_melee_game_data.ccid
ORDER BY sum(t_act_melee_game_data.core_data) DESC
```

Construct in SQLAlchemy;

```
self.db_user_online.query(
    MeleeGameData.ccid,
    func.sum(MeleeGameData.core_data).label("ct")
).\
    group_by(MeleeGameData.ccid).\
    order_by(func.sum(MeleeGameData.core_data).desc()).\
    all()
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try

```py
self.db_user_online.query(
    MeleeGameData,
    func.sum(MeleeGameData.core_data).label("ct")
) \
    .group_by(MeleeGameData.ccid) \
    .filter_by(mid=self.cycle_id) \
    .order_by(desc("ct")) \
    .all()
```